# How create Ninject factory

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, inversion-of-control, ninject

I have an abstract factory. Today, I wanted to bind it with ninject. I do not know which is the best way, but I did it in this way.  Then I tough I tried the by the provider way. so 
I implemented the provider interface. The problem is that, I call in this way   `kernel.Bind<IModelValidator>().ToProvider<ModelValidatingFactory>()`

I can not use IModelValidatingFactory insted of ModelValidatingFactory so I have to give a parameter what is the factory(list). 
I want to creat a factory for the IModelValidator interfaces. I would like to use the class type as the key. How am I able to give a parameter for the constructor, or which is the best way to make it works? What should I use for key, because if I use type I have to pass it, I do not like to use string as type

I watched the `.ToFactory` method of the Ninject, but I do not understand. I saw more implementation possibility. What do you advice me?

```
// this is what I would like to try, but there are some error with this. I can not reference to the type, and I can not give factory
     public class ModelValidatingFactory : Provider<IModelValidator>, TandoCare.Desktop.Infrastructure.ModelValidating.IModelValidatingFactory
        {
            public IDictionary<Type, Func<IModelValidator>> validationFactory = new Dictionary<Type, Func<IModelValidator>>();

            public ModelValidatingFactory(IDictionary<Type, Func<IModelValidator>> factory)
            {
                //validationFactory.Add(typeof(PatientModel), () => new PatientRegistrationValidator());
                validationFactory = factory;
            }

            protected override IModelValidator CreateInstance(Ninject.Activation.IContext context)
            {
                return validationFactory[context.Request.Target.Type]();
            }

            public IModelValidator GetValidator(object model)
            {
                Type type = model.GetType();
                return validationFactory[type]();
            }

            public IModelValidator this[object lookedType]
            {
                get
                {
                    Type type = lookedType.GetType();
                    return validationFactory[type]();
                }
            }
        }
```

how should I use the .ToFactory method in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your concern is that you want to provide a specific constructor argument to your factory, and that constructor argument is not something that Ninject will know how to bind.

You should be able to set up the bindings so that Ninject knows how to produce an instance of your factory. Something like this:

```
kernel.Bind<IModelValidator>()
      .ToProvider<ModelValidatingFactory>();
kernel.Bind<ModelValidatingFactory>()
      .ToConstant(new ModelValidatingFactory(/*pass your parameter */));
```

Comment: how should I create a factory for my problem, can U advice me anything. which is the best solution, should I pass throw the constructor everywhere or inject to the property

Comment: @user1693057: You're talking about the class that wants to consume the factory? I personally prefer constructor injection, but you can google "Constructor vs Property injection" to find the pros and cons of each.